# Can an air core inductor cause a buck converter to malfunction because of EMI?

Tags: inductor, buck, emi-filtering, core

I am trying to build a buck converter circuit using the LM2596T.

While reading its datasheet, it came to my attention that EMI is a potential problem one should not ignore while designing a buck converter.

Since I did not have the recommended inductors at my disposal, I decided to make my own using transformer coils rated for 5 A of current, its inductance should be about 33µH. However, for a certain reason, the regulator's output voltage drops to 2.25V whenever the current reaches 1 A.

Knowing that air core inductors do not get saturated, the issue must lie somewhere else, the only culprit I have in mind is EMI.

How does one "shield" a circuit from the magnetic field of an air core coil?

Buck-converter info:

- Input 12 V
- Output 5 V
- desired current 2.5A
- frequency 150 kHz

Comment: 1) are you sure your homemade inductor is really 33 uH? 2) is your coil behaving as a coil at the switching frequency that the LM2596 is working at? I mean, all coils have a **resonance frequency**, is that frequency high enough? 3) Is the **series resistance** of your inductor low enough? 4) Realize that the LM2596 simply isn't designed to work with air core inductors.

Comment: 5) Don't blame EMI just like that. EMI is about keeping pulsed current loops small so that means you have to keep the inductor - LM2596 - diode loop small.  Using an air coil might mean that your coil is large, that could prevent your design from having a **small loop**. That could make EMI **worse**. 6) Get the correct and recommended type of inductor and try again.

Comment: ESR of the inductor is very low ( about 140mohm) i measured it myself with an accurate shunt , as for the inductor value , I am not 100% certain, but i did apply this formula correctly, https://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9708033.pdf, that aside, i did test a couple of inductors which had the correct value of inductance but kept getting saturated therefore the output voltage kept dropping ( voltage changes everytime i change the inductor ) , and unfortunately i am not able to acquire the recommended inductors as indicated in the datasheets.

Comment: Hmm, one of the recommended 33uH inductors from coilcraft have a DCR of 66 mOhms, so half of that. I'm not saying that 140 mOhms is too high though. Did you measure the resonance frequency? *unfortunately i am not able to acquire the recommended inductors as indicated in the datasheets.* There are also cheap ready-to-use LM2596 modules for sale on Ebay and ALi, for hobby projects, that might be enough and saves the hassle of finding a suitable inductor.

Comment: unfortunately , I do not have the proper tools to do so , I've only got a multi-meter and micro-controllers at my disposal at the moment. is there any way to measure it using something other than an oscilloscope?

Comment: *is there any way to measure it using something other than an oscilloscope?* Yes, a network analyzer. But if you have no access to a scope you might not have acces to an Network aanlyzer or VNA either. So no, it cannot be done with a multimeter.

Comment: Why on earth would you not use a ferrite core inductor? How ginormously large did your air core end up with the thousands of turns needed with thick wire to get 140 mohm? Something is fishy.

Comment: it wasn't that big to be completely honest ,( i thought it'd be bigger) it's 1.96 inches in diameter and 0.39 in in length , if you apply the formula that i posted above it should give you 36 µH of inductance, and I've only needed 17 windings, in addition, i chose to build an aircore inductor since i would simultaneously avoid core power losses and saturation which sounds phenomenal on paper. as for ferrite cores, I intend to buy those as soon as possible but for now, testing the air core inductors is my only option.

Comment: @winny you should also consider the gauge of the wire here, as the wires I chose weren't exactly thin ( I got these wires from this transformer https://tncltd.cafe24.com/PDF/Common/25/CV/CV505110B.pdf.)

Comment: @winny the numbers are strange because we mostly use the metric system in my country so I had to convert from cm to in.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your circuit along with your schematic. Air core inductors can cause problems as the field will couple in to other wires which could mess up your feedback loop and/or cause ground bounce.  BTW, large diameter wire can cause excessive AC losses due to proximity effect. There is a correct wire diameter to use for single frequencies which optimizes DC & AC losses.

Comment: @A.H.Z Did you notice in that article you cited about making air coils, that the formula is only good if the length is at least 40% of the diameter??? Yours is about 20%. So the formula doesn't apply. This is because there is an important assumption in that simplified formula. Your coil is mostly "fringing," which is the part they are assuming isn't important.

Comment: That’s not the reason. Also, why do you insist on air core?

Comment: @winny He says he doesn't want to consider the possibility of core saturation. Air core eliminates that question, entirely. Also, he says he doesn't have ferrite cores available at this time. I would do exactly the same thing were I in the exact same situation. Makes sense to me.

Comment: @jonk Very bad engineering decision on his hand.

Comment: Inserting d=1.96, n=17, l=0.39 into the formula (first formula under "Calculating Air-Core Inductors, L = d^2 * n^2 / (18*d + 40*l)) yields 22 µH, not 36. So even if the formula applied (which it very clearly doesn't), the inductance would still be off by >30%. You need to make the diameter much smaller and use several times more turns.

Comment: @winny Yeah, it's crazy-minded. But when you are limited circumstances, you do crazy-minded things. I easily recall my own times when I couldn't afford or find the "standard solutions" to problems. I am, and was always, a hobbyist. So you do what you can afford to do. Sometimes, that means diving into dumpsters for parts. Sometimes, it means going air-core when everyone else is going ferrite. I don't blame him. I applaud him for working with what's available.

Comment: @jonk That's fine for sure. I remember building my first PA system for <100 € using scrap parts. My issue is with the assertion that "cores can saturate" -> "I should not use them", which is not a good engineering choice. A scrap ATX power supply, salvage a core and some wire and wind your own on the other hand is a great learning experience.

Comment: Power inductors are never air core inductors because it's just impractical. Please once again try using a ferrite core. The idea that @winny had was a really good one. A "Dead" ATX power supply is cheap, and if you're a worthy cause, you can get one for free if you ask the right way. If not, you can try any discarded electronics, and look in the power supply. All switchers (that I've seen) have a switching transformer. The ATX (PC) power supply usually has a really good one. If you find a big ferrite, and it's not the right inductance, you can then rewrap it with your transformer wire.

Comment: If you're on a budget, you can probably still buy a "Transistor Tester", which will give you approximate measurements for inductance and include ESR.  My favorite is the ["GM328 Transistor Tester"](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=gm328+transistor+tester&s=price-asc-rank&crid=2WE7IW569PTQ8&qid=1632332123&sprefix=gm328+tran%2Ctools%2C162&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank) which is less than $20 USD at Amazon. Then, you'll know how much inductance your air coil is, and the ESR of the failed inductors (probably high).  I use one of the "DIY" kits and put it together myself.

Comment: And I believe that the transistor tester is open source, and the Arduino processor, so you might be able to build your own from what you've got. Though it would be challenging.

Comment: One other place for finding a free but good ferrite for making a power inductor -- the flyback transformer from a discarded TV can usually be extricated from its coil, and then you can rewind it with some thick wire and even adjust the air gap (first try keeping the air gap already in place.)  The bigger the TV, usually, the bigger the flyback transformer.